# inject common providers to angularjs controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

There are set of commonly used providers across my angularjs controllers. Eg. $scope, $rootScope, $http and my customer services. I would like to inject those common providers to all controllers without defining each of them in controllers

Eg,

Instead of,

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http){
   .....
}
function MenuCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, MyService){
   .....
}
```

Do this,

```
function HomeCtrl(){
   ...
   // $scope, $rootScope, $http are available here
   ...
}
function MenuCtrl(MyService){
   ...
   // $scope, $rootScope, $http are available here
   ...
}
```

So, in this example $scope, $rootScope, $http are automatically injected to all controllers. But I'm not sure how to do this. Anybody knows a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think spraying all your controllers with the same dependencies is a good idea. It suggests that the application does not have a good structure and you should probably address this.

Taking your example there are a few things that stand out. You don't need to depend on `$scope`and `$rootScope`, you can get the root scope from `$scope` using `$scope.$root`

If you are wrapping logic up in services and reusing code amongst controllers then I would suggest that your controllers don't need to depend on $http, instead move this code into the services that you depend on. Try and name those services appropriately so that you can tell what they do. For instance prefer `AccountCreator` over something more generic like `AccountsService`. In fact never name something `xxxService` the service suffix is a throw a way line that really adds no meaning.

In terms of your actual question, no I don't think there is a way of doing this out of the box. I have some ideas of how you could hack it in, but I think pandoras box should be left locked.

Comment: It's always a good idea to be very explicit about your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer and tips and yes I also don't want to hack the core codes.

Comment: Your welcome, please click answer on the question if you are happy with the answer